# Missing log file

Tags: java, cron

I wrote a .jar file that is supposed to be run once a day that interacts with Google App Engine.  When I run it from the computer, it runs just fine and creates a logfile that details some statistics.  I transferred it over to the Raspberry Pi and it runs via crontab.

The first time I ran it, I got a permission denied in syslog.  I read that using 'sudo crontab -e' would fix that.  Now I no longer get the error but my logfile doesn't appear.

Here is the portion of the code that is to create the logfile:

```
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("log" + format.format(date) + ".txt");
        writer.println("Total Themes: " + numThemes + "\r\n");
        writer.println("Active Themes: " + numActiveThemes + "\r\n");
        writer.println("Inactive Themes: " + numInactiveThemes + "\r\n");
        writer.println("Total Sales: " + numSales + "\r\n");
        writer.println("Total Price Changes: " + numPriceChanges + "\r\n");
        writer.println("Total Time: " + seconds + " seconds" + "\r\n");
        writer.close();
```

Crontab:

```
0 2 * * * java -jar /mnt/data/scripts/test.jar
```

What am I missing about the switch from Windows that is preventing the creation of the logfile?

Edit: I can run the .jar file manually (using sudo) and the logfile is created.  Not working w/cron though.

Edit2: /etc/log/syslog has:

```
Feb  8 21:46:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[10841]: (root) CMD (java -jar /mnt/data/scripts/updater_pricing.jar
```

Edit 3: Changed permissions of the folder and jar to 777 (as a test).  Now I can run the file w/o 'sudo' (expected).  Tried running a regular cron task using the same cron expression as above.  Now syslog has:

```
Feb  9 07:55:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[13292]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/java -jar /mnt/data/scripts/test.jar)
```

It also has:
    Feb  9 07:55:59 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[13291]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Perhaps I can add something that will output the error message?

Comment: What user is running the cronjob and do they have permissions to write in the given directory?

Comment: How do I find out what user? I logged in via the default user "pi" via ssh and did 'sudo crontab -e' I tried changing the permissions of the folder 'scripts' to 777 but appear to get the same result.

Comment: Running crontab under sudo can do some strange things... Does the command need root privileges?  If not try removing it from that file and run 'crontab -e'.  This will run under the user "pi" and may be less error prone.

Comment: It needs to create a file, doesn't that need sudo permissions?

Comment: Not if your user has write privileges to the output folder.

Comment: My last comment didn't post apparently. I tried with the regular cron and the same thing happened... See edit3 above

Comment: crontab sends errors through your system's mail client.  I would suggest installing postfix and configuring it with the smtp service of whatever you use as an email client. Example:  https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/ try that and let us know what error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out thanks to the pointers from @Jacobm001.  The email was being sent because I had some lines of `System.out.println()`

The logfiles were being created, just in the wrong place.  I had to modify the original file line to be:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/mnt/data/scripts/" + "log" + format.format(date) + ".txt");
```

Comment: Congrats, glad to hear you got it working!